# culebra GUI not scaling at all

Tags: android, user-interface, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

i am new to culebra.

I have tried to follow the steps on the wiki page by running.

culebra -G

However, it gives me an oversized image but the command line does not allow me to enter new commands

My image is something like this.

[image]

And my command line is something like this.

[image]

Is there any step by step tutorials i can follow as i cannot seem to follow the wiki. I am running on windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scale the window use

```
python culebra -G --scale=0.5
```

or whatever value suits your needs.

For some reason it's telling you there are no *touchable* or *clickable* views, this may indicate that the dump couldn't be obtained. Try

```
python dump -a
```

to check if this is the case.

## Edit

I've seen views dumped in your autogenerated culebra script (e.g. `no_id1`, `no_id2`, ...) so the case may be you are clicking outside these views.

## EDIT

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> all the *clickable* and *touchable* zones are highlighted

[image]

Comment: Which view should I be clicking on? The emulator itself or the screen capture?

Comment: You can click on both, depending on the case. If you change the emulator (by interacting with it) then you have to refresh culebra (pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>) to reconcile.

Comment: Normally, you interact only with the `culebra` window,

Comment: I have tried clicking inside the screen capture but it shows the nothing is clickable. If I were to click the emulator and press refresh for the screen capture it will take very long to load before saying not responding

Comment: Yet another trick, if you press Ctrl-Z you'll see the clickable zones.